# CocoaHTTPServer2.3 Implicit declaration of function 'LOG_OBJC_MAYBE' is invalid in C99

Tags: objective-c, logging, swift3

I use the last version of  `pod 'CocoaHTTPServer', '~> 2.3'` and xcode Version 8.1 beta (8T29o) and swift 3.0

When i install this pod i get this error on HTTPLogError  (and other method of HTTPLoging.h).

```
/Volumes/app/Project_ios/Pods/CocoaHTTPServer/Extensions/WebDAV/DAVResponse.m:102:9: Implicit declaration of function 'LOG_OBJC_MAYBE' is invalid in C99
```

Comment: I also have this same issue , and is not quiet solved. What I did was to removed all the cocoa lumber jack functions in cocoahttpserver pod (Not a good thing). 

The issue I suspects is that cocoalumberjack have only support for xcode 8 and swift 3 . The backward compatibility is for xcode 7.3 and swift 2.3 .

Answer (score 18):

I did the following steps to solve the problem:

Step 1: change `#import "DDLog.h"` to `#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>` in file `HTTPLogging.h`

Step 2: replace all `LOG_OBJC_MAYBE` with `HTTP_LOG_OBJC_MAYBE` and all `LOG_C_MAYBE` with `HTTP_LOG_C_MAYBE` in file `HTTPLogging.h`

Step 3: add the following macro in file `HTTPLogging.h`

```
#define HTTP_LOG_OBJC_MAYBE(async, lvl, flg, ctx, frmt, ...) \
do{ if(HTTP_LOG_ASYNC_ENABLED) LOG_MAYBE(async, lvl, flg, ctx, nil, sel_getName(_cmd), frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); } while(0)

#define HTTP_LOG_C_MAYBE(async, lvl, flg, ctx, frmt, ...) \
do{ if(HTTP_LOG_ASYNC_ENABLED) LOG_MAYBE(async, lvl, flg, ctx, nil, __FUNCTION__, frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

Hope my experience can give help.